# How to convert Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY to BigDecimal?

Tags: java

I tried `BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY)`, but kept getting `NumberFormatException`

Thanks

Comment: `BigDecimal infinity = BigDecimal.ZERO; for(;;) infinity = infinity.add(BigDecimal.ONE);`

Comment: The best solution that I can think of is to implement a subclass of BigDecimal that has this ability, if you need the features of both BigDecimal and Infinity.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This behavior corresponds to the [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf%28double%29) way the `valueOf` method is supposed to work:

> Parameters: val - double to convert to a BigDecimal.
>
> Returns: a BigDecimal whose value is equal to or approximately equal to the value of val.
>
> Throws: NumberFormatException - if val is **infinite** or NaN.

Answer (score 16):

You cannot represent infinity in `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 1):

Use Double.MIN_VALUE and Double.MAX_VALUE

Answer (score 0):

You cannot simply derive a child class from BigDecimal to support NaN and Infinite. When deriving a child class, the constructors of parent have to be implemented. And the parent constructor have to be called first in the child constructor.
BigDecimal has a number of constructors, e.g. BigDecimal(double val). However, as JAVA doc points out, double val should not be NaN or infinite. Otherwise, a NumberFormatException throws. If you extends BigDecimal to MyBigDecimal, I think you also need a similar constructor  which is MyBigDecimal(double val). Problem is, MyBigDecimal(double val) has to call super(val) as the first statement (Java requirement). You can not add something like if(val == Double.NaN) or try catch before super(val). So the MyBigDecimal(double val) function has to be like:

```
public MyBigDecimal(double val) {
    super(val);
    ...
}
```

As such there is no way to set val to Double.NaN or Infinite because this results in NumberFormatException anyway.

More unfortunately, BigDecimal is a read only class, i.e. you have no way to reset its value using a function like setValue(...). So you can never assign NaN or infinite to a BigDecimal extended class.

The only solution is using a wrapper, i.e.

```
class MyBigDecimal {
    public BigDecimal mbigDecNormalValue;
    public double mdNaNOrInf;
    ...
```

clearly, this will not be a very simple implementation.

It is pretty strange that Oracle hasn't supported BigDecimal NaN or infinite in JAVA 7. But I believe BigDecimal will finally support these values. I would suggest don't touch NaN or infinite when you use BigDecimal at this moment. Otherwise after NaN and infinite are supported, user defined MyBigDecimal could conflict with the new BigDecimal interfaces and inevitably causes pretty much overhead coding